# How to insert values to a column(ExamPassed) based the content of another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, vba

I have a sheet which contains data like this:

[image]

Now 3 people(Jane, George, and Ryan) inside this table passed the exam.

I want to set their `ExamPassed` value to `v`. How can I do this with excel formulas?

I mean at the end of this operation. The table will look like this:

[image]

The 3 people's names are stored in another table like this:

[image]

Comment: Since i don'd know the names of your worksheets change as required. Paste this formula in C2, of the first work sheet and Drag the fill handle down as far as you need to.  `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A, Sheet1!B:B)=1, "V", "")`

Comment: Is this Excel? Or Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

C2:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A$1:A$10,1,0)),"","v")
```

Drag fill down

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,Sheet2!A:A,1,0)),,"v"))
```

Comment: I would use `MATCH` instead of `VLOOKUP` to avoid even trying to return a value from the destination range. If OP expands their desired summary table (e.g. to include the passing score, proctor, and other content from the student's row in the destination), `VLOOKUP` would be fine for a bit, but for enough rows a single MATCH column and then repeated destination accesses with `INDEX` will provide significant performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

In C2 of sheet1 (and drag down):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4=B2)),"v","")
```

[image: Data]

Or

```
=CHOOSE(SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4=B2))+1,"","v")
```